# Email Template body NULL when UItype is Lightning or Lighting Sample

Tags: soql, email-template

When querying the EmailTemplate Object all body fields are null if the uiType is set to lightning or sample lightning.

Sample query: `SELECT Name, Subject, Body, uiType FROM EmailTemplate`

## Actual Result:

[image]

## Expected Result:

All body fields are not blank and contain the Text values in each respective HTMLValue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following query:
HtmlValue is populated for SFX.

```
SELECT Name, Subject, Body, uiType,HtmlValue,MarkUp FROM EmailTemplate
```